# How to make my Haskell program faster? Comparison with C

Tags: performance, haskell, profiling

I'm working on an implementation of one of the SHA3 candidates, JH. I'm at the point where the algorithm pass all KATs (Known Answer Tests) provided by NIST, and have also made it an instance of the Crypto-API. Thus I have began looking into its performance. But I'm quite new to Haskell and don't really know what to look for when profiling.

At the moment my code is consistently slower then the reference implementation written in C, by a factor of 10 for all input lengths (C code found here: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/wuhj/research/jh/jh_bitslice_ref64.h).

My Haskell code is found here: https://github.com/hakoja/SHA3/blob/master/Data/Digest/JHInternal.hs.

Now I don't expect you to wade through all my code, rather I would just want some tips on a couple of functions. I have run some performance tests and this is (part of) the performance file generated by GHC:

```
Tue Oct 25 19:01 2011 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

   main +RTS -sstderr -p -hc -RTS jh e False

total time  =        6.56 secs   (328 ticks @ 20 ms)
total alloc = 4,086,951,472 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                    MODULE               %time %alloc

roundFunction                  Data.Digest.JHInternal  28.4   37.4
word128Shift                   Data.BigWord.Word128  14.9   19.7
blockMap                       Data.Digest.JHInternal  11.9   12.9
getBytes                       Data.Serialize.Get     6.7    2.4
unGet                          Data.Serialize.Get     5.5    1.3
sbox                           Data.Digest.JHInternal   4.0    7.4
getWord64be                    Data.Serialize.Get     3.7    1.6
e8                             Data.Digest.JHInternal   3.7    0.0
swap4                          Data.Digest.JHInternal   3.0    0.7
swap16                         Data.Digest.JHInternal   3.0    0.7
swap8                          Data.Digest.JHInternal   1.8    0.7
swap32                         Data.Digest.JHInternal   1.8    0.7
parseBlock                     Data.Digest.JHInternal   1.8    1.2
swap2                          Data.Digest.JHInternal   1.5    0.7
swap1                          Data.Digest.JHInternal   1.5    0.7
linearTransform                Data.Digest.JHInternal   1.5    8.6
shiftl_w64                     Data.Serialize.Get     1.2    1.1

Detailed breakdown omitted ...
```

Now quickly about the JH algorithm:

It's a hash algorithm which consists of a compression function F8, which is repeated as long as there exists input blocks (of length 512 bits). This is just how the SHA-functions operate. The F8 function consists of the E8 function which applies a round function 42 times. The round function itself consists of three parts:
a sbox, a linear transformation and a permutation (called swap in my code).

Thus it's reasonable that most of the time is spent in the round function. Still I would like to know how those parts could be improved. For instance: the blockMap function is just a utility function, mapping a function over the elements in a 4-tuple. So why is it performing so badly? Any suggestions would be welcome, and not just on single functions, i.e. are there structural changes you would have done in order to improve the performance?

I have tried looking at the Core output, but unfortunately that's way over my head.

I attach some of the heap profiles at the end as well in case that could be of interest.

**EDIT :**

I forgot to mention my setup and build. I run it on a x86_64 Arch Linux machine, GHC 7.0.3-2 (I think), with compile options:

> ghc --make -O2 -funbox-strict-fields

Unfortunately [there seems to be a bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5043) on the Linux plattform when compiling via C or LLVM, giving me the error:

> Error: .size expression for XXXX does not evaluate to a constant

so I have not been able to see the effect of that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What package is Data.BigWord from?

Comment: Data.BigWord.Word128 is in the linked git repo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Switch to unboxed Vectors (from Array, used for constants)
- Use [`unsafeIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:unsafeIndex) instead of incurring the bounds check and data dependency from safe indexing (i.e. `!`)
- Unpack `Block1024` as you did with `Block512` (or at least use `UnboxedTuples`)
- Use `unsafeShift{R,L}` so you don't incur the check on the shift value (coming in GHC 7.4)
- Unfold the `roundFunction` so you have one rather ugly and verbose `e8` function.  This was significat in pureMD5 (the rolled version was prettier but massively slower than the unrolled version).  You might be able to [use TH to do](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-February/056248.html) this and keep the code smallish.  If you do this then you'll have no need for `constants` as these values will be explicit in the code and result in a more cache friendly binary.
- Unpack your `Word128` values.
- Define your own addition for `Word128`, don't lift `Integer`.  See LargeWord for [an example](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/largeword/1.0.1/doc/html/src/Data-LargeWord.html#LargeKey) of how this can be done.
- [`rem` not `mod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841078/why-map-digittoint-show-is-so-fast/4846729#4846729)
- Compile with optimization (`-O2`) and try llvm (`-fllvm`)

EDIT: And cabalize your git repo along with a benchmark so we can help you easier ;-).  Good work on including a crypto-api instance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, really appreciate it. I will cabalize it up soon...I just don't know how to do it yet :-) That TH stuff seemed a little complicated, but I will try it out. When I try to compile via C (or ffvlm) I get this strange compilation error: ".size expression for XXX does not evaluate to a constant". It seems like this is a bug on the Linux plattform (I run on Arch Linux x86_64), so unfortunately I have not been able to test the effects of that. How can I unpack Block1024? I get a compilation error when I try.

Comment: What did you mean with "..you'll have no need for constants as these values will be explicit in the code..."? Will I have to include them in the e8 function explicitely? Won't that be rally messy? As to making my own addition for Word128: You're absolutely right. Originally I used the LargeWord package, but it contained some bugs, so I just rolled my own temporarily.

Comment: It will probably be messy, but it's a mess TH takes care of.

Comment: @hakoja To unpack `Block1024` you'll need to make it a `data` instead of a `type` declaration (and add a constructor, obviously).  Your LLVM error could be due to the version of GHC or LLVM you have installed.  Including the constants in e8 explicitly is messy, but would be a speed benefit.  The mess can be avoided with the TH trick if you decide to try that.

Comment: @hakoja Also, if you have the time then consider sending in a patch adding a module `Test.JH` to `crypto-api-tests`.  See the `Test.AES` and `Test.MD5` modules for examples.

Answer (score 8):

The lower graph shows that a lot of memory is occupied by lists. Unless there are more lurking in other modules, they can only come from `e8`. Maybe you'll have to bite the bullet and make that a loop instead of a fold, but for starters, since `Block1024` is a pair, the `foldl'` doesn't do much evaluation on the fly (unless the strictness analyser has become significantly better). Try making that stricter, `data Block1024 = B1024 !Block512 !Block512`, perhaps it also needs `{-# UNPACK #-}` pragmas. In `roundFunction`, use `rem` instead of `mod` (this will only have minor impact, but it's a bit faster) and make the `let` bindings strict. In the `swapN` functions, you might get better performance giving the constants in the form `W x y` rather than as 128-bit hex numbers.
I can't guarantee those changes will help, but that's what looks most promising after a short glance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, see my reply to Thomas M. DuBuisson, further down regarding unfolding e8. Adding bang patterns to Block1024 gives me a compilation error :/ how can I remedy that? I will try out those swapN changes. That is to circumvent one level of constructors right?

Comment: Hm, what compilation error? In a data declaration, the '!' are strictness annotations that are in Haskell98 and Haskell2010, I don't remember any problems using those together with bang patterns. The point of the suggested change in the `swapN` functions is that with `W x y` you get two 64-bit words (hopefully literals) instead of an intermediate `Integer`. It may not make any difference if the optimiser is good enough.

Comment: It gives me:     Unexpected strictness annotation: !Block512
    In the type synonym declaration for `Block1024'

Comment: Ah, I see. It can't be a type synonym with strictness annotations. That requires a `data` declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I thought I would chime in with an update of what I have done and the results obtained thus far. Changes made:

- Switched from Array to UnboxedArray (made Word128 an instance type)
- Used UnboxedArray + fold in e8 instead of lists and (prelude) fold
- Used unsafeIndex instead of !
- Changed type of Block1024 to a real datatype (similiar to Block512), and unpacked its arguments
- Updated GHC to version 7.2.1 on Arch Linux, thus fixing the problem with compiling via C or LLVM
- Switched mod to rem in some places, but NOT in **roundFunction**. When I do it there, the compile time suddenly takes an awful lot of time, and the run time becomes 10 times slower! Does anyone know why that may be? It is only happening with GHC-7.2.1, not GHC-7.0.3

I compile with the following options:

> ghc-7.2.1 --make -O2 -funbox-strict-fields main.hs ./Tests/testframe.hs -fvia-C -optc-O2

And the results? Roughly 50 % reduction in time. On an input of ~107 MB, the code now use 3 minutes as compared to the previous 6-7 minutes. The C version uses 42 seconds.

Things I tried, but which didn't result in better performance:

- Unrolled the e8 function like this:

  > e8 !h = go h 0
  >
  > where go !x !n
  >
  > ```
  >       | n == 42   = x
  >       | otherwise = go h' (n + 1)
  >       where !h' = roundFunction x n
  > ```
- Tried breaking up the swapN functions to use the underlying Word64' directly:

  > swap1 (W xh hl) =
  >
  > ```
  >      shiftL (W (xh .&. 0x5555555555555555) (xl .&. 0x5555555555555555)) 1 
  >      .|. 
  >      shiftR (W (xh .&. 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) (xl .&. 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)) 1
  > ```
- Tried using the LLVM backend

All of these attempts gave worse performance than what I have currently. I don't know if thats because I'm doing it wrong (especially the unrolling of e8), or because they just are worse options.

Still I have some new questions with these new tweaks.

1. Suddenly I have gotten this peculiar bump in memory usage. Take a look at following heap profiles:
   [image]
   [image]

   Why has this happened? Is it because of the UnboxedArray? And what does SYSTEM mean?
2. When I compile via C I get the following warning:

   > Warning: The -fvia-C flag does nothing; it will be removed in a future GHC release

   Is this true? Why then, do I see better performance using it, rather than not?

Comment: As of 7.2.1, -fvia-C is officially gone. Any performance difference you see is probably just normal jittering due to other activities on the computer. If you can get stable measurements showing a difference between code compiled with -fvia-C and without, that'd be an oddity worth deeper investigation (bug report).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you did a fair amount of tweaking already; I'm curious what the performance is like without explicit strictness annotations (`BangPatterns`) and the various compiler pragmas (`UNPACK`, `INLINE`)...  Also, a dumb question: what optimization flags are you using?

Anyway, two suggestions which may be completely awful:

1. Use unboxed primitive types where you can (e.g. replace `Data.Word.Word64` with `GHC.Word.Word64#`, make sure `word128Shift` is using `Int#`, etc.) to avoid heap allocation.  This is, of course, non-portable.
2. Try `Data.Sequence` instead of `[]`

At any rate, rather than looking at the Core output, try looking at the intermediate C files (`*.hc`) instead.  It can be hard to wade through, but sometimes makes it obvious where the compiler wasn't quite as sharp as you'd hoped.

Comment: Well, I would rather suggest to use `Data.Vector` instead of `Data.Sequence`, since the former has a nice loop-fusion framework that works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'm just using -O2 and -funbox-strict-fields (see edit above for why). The annotations and pragmas gives just a small bump in performance, but enough to justify being there, exept for one which is absolutely crucial: Without the bangpattern in f8 I get a stack overflow or massive heap allocation. Now it runs in constant space and 98 % efficiency :) Where would I use Vector/Sequence? Can it give me something more than just for the constants array? The only places I use lists are in e8 and parseMessage. Is there potential for fusion other places than e8?